# pygame blitting - center

Tags: python, pygame, centering

I am trying to make a script in python for pygame to draw a button with text centered, but when I blit onto the screen, it blits to the x and y I give it, not a proportionally centered location. I want to be able to center it to a set of (x,y,w,h). How would I do this? Here's my code:

```
# Imports
import pygame

class Text:
    'Centered Text Class'
    # Constructror
    def __init__(self, text, (x,y,w,h), color = (0,0,0)):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        # Start PyGame Font
        pygame.font.init()
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("sans", 20)
        self.txt = font.render(text, True, color)
    # Draw Method
    def Draw(self, screen):
        coords = (self.x, self.y)
        screen.blit(self.txt, coords)
```

Edit: Comments, yes I know but I only used x and y as temporary variables because I have no idea what the centered x and y would be to center the text. (I want to know how to center its CENTER to a rect, not its top left corner)

Comment: But width and height have nothing to do with X and Y positions.

Comment: What proportionally centered location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the font.size() method to determine how large the rendered text will be.

Something like:

```
class Text:
    """Centered Text Class"""
    # Constructror
    def __init__(self, text, (x,y), color = (0,0,0)):
        self.x = x #Horizontal center of box
        self.y = y #Vertical center of box
        # Start PyGame Font
        pygame.font.init()
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("sans", 20)
        self.txt = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.size = font.size(text) #(width, height)
    # Draw Method
    def Draw(self, screen):
        drawX = self.x - (self.size[0] / 2.)
        drawY = self.y - (self.size[1] / 2.)
        coords = (drawX, drawY)
        screen.blit(self.txt, coords)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think something like the following does what you want. It uses `pygame.font.Font.size()` to determine the amount of space needed to render the text, and then centers that within rectangular region defined by `CenteredText` instance.

```
class CenteredText(object):
    """ Centered Text Class
    """
    def __init__(self, text, (x,y,w,h), color=(0,0,0)):
        self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h = x,y,w,h
        pygame.font.init()
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("sans", 20)
        width, height = font.size(text)
        xoffset = (self.w-width) // 2
        yoffset = (self.h-height) // 2
        self.coords = self.x+xoffset, self.y+yoffset
        self.txt = font.render(text, True, color)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.txt, self.coords)
        # for testing purposes, draw the rectangle too
        rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), rect, 1)
```

Given:

```
text = CenteredText('Hello world', (200,150,100,100))
```

Here's the results from calling `text.draw(screen)` in a 500x400 pixel window.

[image: screenshot of sample output]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perfectly centre an object:
When you give Pygame coordinates for an object it takes them to be the coordinates for the upper left corner. Thus we have to halve the x and y coordinates.

```
coords = (self.x/2, self.y/2)
screen.blit(self.txt, coords)
```

Other than that your question is unclear.

Comment: This works but it only centers the top-left section of the text, and I want the center of the text at the center of x and y

Comment: `objectrect = object.get_rect()` Then set those coords to the ones you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Let pygame do the maths for you by using `Rect`s and assigning the text's center to the destination center:

```py
# Start PyGame Font
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("sans", 20)

class Text:
    'Centered Text Class'
    # Constructror
    def __init__(self, text, (x,y,w,h), color = (0,0,0)):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.txt = font.render(text, True, color)
    # Draw Method
    def Draw(self, screen):
        coords = self.txt.get_rect()
        coords.center = self.rect.center
        screen.blit(self.txt, coords)
```